# Beginner to Shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have done quite a bit of research, but the information is a bit overwhelming, I am not sure I am taking in the right kind of information at the steps I need to be taking.

Just some basic questions to start me of:

I have read a few tutorials and managed to write a small script of my own, but I have noticed things different in each individuals' scripts that has me puzzled.

Since I really don't know how to ask these questions or in which order I should ask them, I will just unload a few.

How do I know when I need to append `.sh` to the file?
Why do some scripts start off the same, as in `#!/bin/bash`, but some of them have `.sh` appended to the file and some don't?

I guess I have a lot more questions, but to start off, the big ones are the two I have just asked. I am just confused as to how I should... "declare" my shell scripts.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I know when I need to append .sh to the file?

File extension is just a flag for you and maybe some other "clever" programs indicating what sort of content is inside it. It is not necessary.

> Why do some scripts start off the same, as in #!/bin/bash, but some of them have .sh appended to the file and some don't?

[Shebang](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html) inside file `X.sh` allows it to be executable like `$> ./X.sh`.

And a little advice:take some random problem or task, maybe not really useful, and try to solve it with `bash`. And these [two](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) [guys](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage) could help you a lot.

Comment: Search for `sha-bang` on the linked page to get to the relevant material.

Answer (score 2):

1. `.sh` is optional (like how text files don't always have `.txt` extension). It does allow user to identify it as a shell script.
2. `#!/bin/bash` is called 'shebang' (or 'hashbang'). Wikipedia has a pretty decent [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on it.

   Shebang is only used when you execute the script. It specifies which interpreter is to be used when your script is executed. Without shebang, the default shell is used to interpret the script.

   If your shebang is `#!/bin/bash`, and you execute your script like `./script.sh`, it is equivalent to typing this in console:

   ```
   /bin/bash ./script.sh
   ```

---

To make your script executable, you need to

```
    chmod +x script.sh
```

---

Demo of shebang ('script' that prints first five lines of itself)

1. create a file `printmeself` with this content

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/head -5
   I will be printed
   I will be printed 2
   I will be printed 3
   I will be printed 4
   I won't be printed
   Bye
   ```
2. `chmod +x printmeself`
3. `./printmeself`
4. ???
5. Profit

Answer (score 0):

1. `.sh` is just a convention which helps the user to know if it is a shell script without even opening the file. Its not mandatory for shell scripts to have this convention. However, its advised to use this.
2. `#!/bin/bash` is the magic line written to the beginning of the file which tells in which shell the script has to be executed. Syntaxes are different for different shells. Hence, when you write a shell script, it is advised to specify the shell which you want this script to be executed with. If not specified, the kernel will decide the shell which could be either bourne shell or same as the login shells.